# how do I easily find the SATA port an HDD is connected to in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

In linux, I can easily associate a disk with a SATA port as ADA0 would correspond to the first SATA port.

I am trying to do the same in Windows 10 but I'm finding it's not so easy. I'm fairly new to using Windows 10 after having use macOS/Linux for so long.

I've looked at Device Manager and I cannot see the SATA bus/port the drive is connected to.

There are 6 HDDs of the same model connected to the motherboard SATA ports. I need to replace 1.

Any tips on how to do it using built-in/3rd-party tools?

Thanks

Comment: I am unaware of even third part tools which do as you ask. As you already know, the best "third part tool" for this is actually linux. `HWiNFO64` does not display this information either, it only shows out of order SMART status. Honestly, just boot live linux if you really want this information without hardware disassembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

Press your Windows key then type

> diskmgmt.msc

[image]

Then hit enter

A window will appear where you can see all your HDDs

[image]

You can now right-click then click on Properties
so you can know where is that HDD plugged

[image]

Right here you can see which SATA port your HDD is using

[image]

Another way to do this is right in the File explorer

Just right-click on the drive
Properties>(on the properties window) click on Hardware
and there it is on Location that's where is your HDD connected

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: One interesting twist I've found: if you plug in an NVMe drive in [this motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H370M-ITXac),  it disables one of the SATA slots (presumably due to shared PCIe lanes), and then you end up with two drives that are both listed on Bus 0. As long as you can work out which one is the NVMe drive, you can still work out which is in which slot, of course.